# Is there a function or command on any of these modules that allow me to read excel data, covert it to text directly from excel to python?

Tags: python, pandas, quandl

**I'm new with programing (main challenge)** with Python and so far Python is my favorite programming language. Anyways, I would like to finish my first project using Quandl but I'm stuck need support.

I have this code, to pull Quandl stocks- however, I don't want to input my tickers on my TextEditor/Sublime either by typing or pasting in.

**THE GOAL**: I want to pull my ticker data from a spreadsheet, then run the .py file.

**Is there a way to read cell data and input into this line of code as a string, so I get the cell data to show as ['AAPL', 'MSFT'....'FB'] or ['A1', 'A2', 'A3'.......'A10']**

```
data = quandl.get_table('WIKI/PRICES', ticker = ['AAPL', 'MSFT', 'WMT']
```

TO:

`data = quandl.get_table('WIKI/PRICES', ticker = **(READ TICKERS PULLED FROM EXCELSTOCKDATA.PY** ['read/write cell A1', 'read/write cell A2'....''read/write cell A10']`,

I've read some of the package docs, seen YouTube examples and can't seem to solve, so I'm reaching out for your wisdom!

Here's an example of what it would look like on python if I wanted to analyzed 10+ stocks (maybe more below not sure as I copied and pasted here) but this is absolutely crazy to type in all the info by hand into python or to copy and paste as the text is also crazy. There has to be a faster method using one line of code?

GetQuandlData.py

```
data = quandl.get_table(['AAPL', 'MSFT','NFLX','FB','GS','TSLA','BAC','TWTR','COF','TOL','EA','PFE','MS','C','SKX','GLD','SPY','EEM']
```

further background:

My secondary file on reading excel data:

readstockdata.py

```
df = pd.read_excel("StockTickerData.xlsx", sheet_name = 'Control')
df = tickers
```

I guess I'd like to do this:

`data = quandl.get_table('WIKI/PRICES', ticker = **(READ TICKERS PULLED FROM EXCELSTOCKDATA.PY** ['read/write cell A1', 'read/write cell A2'....''read/write cell A10']`,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the right idea with pulling in the data from excel as a dataframe.

You should store the data in one column with the first line as a header (e.g. Tickers). Then read it as a dataframe with pandas like you have. After that to get your list, you can run:

```
tickerList = list(df['Tickers'])
```

Comment: I just tried it- and got this when I printed it. ['AAON', 'ABUS', 'ADRD', 'ABDC', 'AFIN', 'BRY', 'FC', 'AOK', 'WU', 'PFBC', 'FB', 'AAL'] this is fantastic! Thank you! Now that I have as a string would I have to copy and paste this list to my program? I don't know how to proceed next to pull tickers into my main program? would i use something like this? 

data = quandl.get_table('WIKI/PRICES', ticker = tickerList(df(['Tickers']) 
or 
data = quandl.get_table('WIKI/PRICES', ticker = List(df(['Tickers'])

Comment: I can't seem to figure out how to input that line of code- any suggestions, i ran it and I get a printout but how do I tell Python to pull those printed strings?

Comment: I don't know how quandl works, but I assume you can do data = quandl.get_table('WIKI/PRICES', ticker=tickerList). The code I gave you before stores the list into a variable. That variable can be used to pass in the list to the function. Hope this helps.

Comment: Ah! okay, that makes sense! Okay, what a major lesson I just learned. I'm curious, but what else can you do with a variable- any cool tricks using other excel packages? Thank you by the way. I do really appreciate you helping me out. I'll give this a try.

Comment: So, I ran it and this is what I got from sublime: ['AAON', 'ABUS', 'ADRD', 'ABDC', 'AFIN', 'BRY', 'FC', 'AOK', 'WU', 'PFBC', 'FB', 'AAL']
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []
When I check the output excel file, there's no data written in it- if python says it's an empty data frame could it be that python isn't reading it correctly as a text/string?